# Unable to make the oauth2Login as stateless

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have provided the cookie based authorization request repository to oauth2Login() dsl to make it as stateless. but when I add the session creation policy as `STATELESS` , the oauth2 login is not working and returning "too many callbacks" error in UI page.

I have used the following oauth2Login config. for login with google oauth2 provider.

```
    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/oauth2/authorization/google")
                .and()
                .sessionManagement(sessionMgmtConfig -> sessionMgmtConfig.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Config -> oauth2Config
                        .authorizationEndpoint(config -> config.authorizationRequestRepository(httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository))
                        .userInfoEndpoint(config -> config.oidcUserService(oidcUserOAuth2UserService()))
                        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler())
                )
                ;//.logout(logoutConfig -> logoutConfig.addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler()))
    }

    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRequestCache(new CookieRequestCache());

        return successHandler;
    }
```

If I comment out the session management line, it is working as expected and creating the JSESSION but when not working if I uncomment this part. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

It is not so easy to have *oauth2Login* and *stateless* *sessionManagement*.
The problem is that Spring needs to store information about OAuth 2.0 `state` parameter. Normally it is stored in session but when you disable it, Spring gets crazy ("too many callbacks") because it can not find it.

To solve that problem you can use your own cookie to store `state` parameter.
This can be done by providing a custom implementation of `AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest>`.

There is a nice blog post descriging everything in more details.

> https://www.jessym.com/articles/stateless-oauth2-social-logins-with-spring-boot

> [What is the purpose of the 'state' parameter in OAuth authorization request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132066/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-state-parameter-in-oauth-authorization-request)

Comment: Hi Pawel, I have provided the `HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository ` which is implemenation of `AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest>` where it will store the necessary info in cookies (in above code configuration I have mentioned). but even after that I'm not able to solve this problem

Comment: Please see an example from the blog post or provide more details.

Comment: Remember to configure it with method  authorizationRequestRepository
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2login-advanced.html

Comment: Here is the source code [link](https://github.com/maradanasai/google-oauth2-autoconfigure-demo) I'm using

Comment: This might be helpful too: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-security-5-oauth-20-login-and-signup-in-sta